# Does global sperm count decline also mean lower testosterone?

Tags: reproduction

So I read about the sperm count decline in men in rich countries. 
I wonder if this is accompanied by other changes for example in testosterone levels or in other hormones linked with the reproductive system ? 
Also other measures such as semen volume ?
Example report on this issue
https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/07/170726110954.htm

Also, the report shows a steady decline - will this continue and what would be the bottoming out of this trend ?

Comment: With an aging population, thanks to better medical science lower average testosterone and sperm is to be expected. If the study is not accounting for this it is pointless.

Comment: Obesity is an important confounder here as well.

Comment: Adding another question.

Comment: Levine, H., Jørgensen, N., Martino-Andrade, A., Mendiola, J., Weksler-Derri, D., Mindlis, I., ... & Swan, S. H. (2017). Temporal trends in sperm count: a systematic review and meta-regression analysis. Human Reproduction Update, 23(6), 646-659. is the actual citation for the study.

Comment: I think I'm half way to finding an answer
https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/03/180318144836.htm